# How to create timeline chart with average using Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am ingesting data to elasticsearch using flume, I want to create a time-series graph in kibana to show the events collected over time. BUT I also want to to the average per that time unit so the user knows if the current flow is around the average or not.

To create a timeline I am using line graph with @timestamp as X-axis and count as Y-axis.

The question is how to create the average line? and how to make this average dynamic e.g. as we zoom in average changes from average per day to average per hour.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem nowadays. I don't know how to represent the average line that would indicate me if all is correct. Have you found any solution? I think that the moving average is the line you need to represent but I can not fully understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

While creating a visualization you can choose the type of y-axis metric. The default is "count". You can click on the icon to choose other type of metrics you want. It will have various options like average, sum, percentile etc.

[image]

As for the time range of average calculation, the the x-axis metrics, under buckets when you choose date histogram the default interval is auto.This means that the time range of average will chage automatically depending on overall time range selected.

[image]

You can change it to a fixed interval like per second, minute, hourly daily etc.

Comment: One line in my chart is `@timestamp` on X and count on Y but I also want to add Average(count(events)) as a second line. by itself I can't use Average on the `@timestamp` field.

Comment: you can add additional metric on the y-axis. There is "+ Add metrics" below the y-axis icon. There you can add another metrics for average.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but as much as I can tell the average aggregation  try to average the values of the field were I am trying to average cout of instances . E.g average the other metric.

Comment: May be I am not getting the exact scenario. The metric "count" in y-axis simply counts the number of document in the time range (per minute or per hour etc as per x-axis). If you choose a metric other than count, say average or sum or percentile then you will need to specify the field on which the function has to be applied. These function is applied on the value of specified field in each of the document (in the time range). I am not sure what you meant by "average count of instances".

Comment: Your explanation is corret. but What I am looking for is to have on one line the count of messages flying to the system (this is solved using the above metrics) AND also have a second average line which represent the average number of messages flying to the system in a time period - so if the first line is similar to the second then all good but if they are different then we see we have a problem. to do the second line I need something like average (count # of messages(given time period)))

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd, you would expect count to appear alongside field as something you can average.  In reality you have to do it another way:

For the Y axis, instead of selecting count, select "Average Bucket"
then set up your bucket aggregation that you would like e.g. Date Histogram with second interval.

Below this you have another box for metric, e.g. the thing you're averaging, set this to count

[image]